# Receiving money in US for work performed overseas

Tags: united-states, income-tax, non-resident

I previously lived in the US on a work visa and so have a bank account there, but am now living overseas (with no tax residency status in the US). I am performing freelance contract work for a US company and they want to pay me into my old US account, which I can then transfer here.

If the work is performed while overseas and I am not an employee of that company, do I need to declare this to the IRS or just my home country? (there is a tax treaty with this country and I have an SSN from working in the US)